# How to add .5 years to a date in a cell using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add 1.5 years or 8.5 years on a cell which is a date. I used the DateAdd function but when i try to add .5 years, it does not work. It could only add full years such as 1, 2..... Is there a way that I can add half years?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the months:

```
=EDATE(A1,8.5*12)
```

[image]

in vba we can use `DateAdd`:

```
 NewDate = DateAdd("m", 8.5 * 12, OldDate)
```

Comment: If this worked for you, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 1):

DateAdd ( interval, number, date ) as you can see DateAdd take 3 parameters. The interval parameter can be yyyy (year), q (quarter), m (month), y (day of year), d (day), w (week day), ww (week), h (hour), n (minute), s (second). It appears you are adding years. Use the m interval and add the number of months.

Comment: Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

Dates in Excel are recorded as integers, just formatted and displayed in a specific way. You can add to dates the same way as with any other number, without needing to input a function.

If you record todays date (9 March 2020) into cell A1, you can add a year to today's date by simply writing `=A1+365`. Alternatively, to add half a year, `=A1+(365/2)`

Comment: Not Integers... Floats. `365/2` is a bad idea. You're forgetting about leap years.